# How to mention URL while submitting ajax form?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using HTML/JQuery/AJax to call a servlet. I am submitting a form to servlet. But it always gives 404 saying resource not found. i have maven project.

I have Servlet in `src/main/java` package is : `com.mycompany.sample`

I have jsp in `webapp/public` folder.

in web.xml i registered servlet using url pattern `/myController`

in jsp i gave action to my form as below:

```
<form action="myController" ...............
```

and i have a separate .js file where i mentioned ajax call as below"

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myController",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(msg) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function(ob,errStr) {
            alert('onfailure');
        }
    });
```

But i always get 404 error saying `/myController` resource is not found and i get `onfailure` alert.

Am i giving correct reference to `myController` in my `form` and in `ajax` call?

Thanks!

Comment: Is myController a file? The URL needs to point to a file. What are you trying to send your data to exactly?

Comment: it is a servlet registered in web.xml

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread the question. Maybe try using the full path.

Comment: Try typing the entire URL in your browser.  If you still get a 404 then you know you're building the wrong URL.  If you get the page you're expecting then you know it's your code/configuration.

Comment: it is referring..http://localhost:8080/MyApp/public/myController...so am getting 404..but this url is correct ..http://localhost:8080/MyApp/public/myController    how can i refer this in my ajax code?

Answer (score 2):

Like other say, try the full path because I think the cause of your 404 is the missing application context.

I don't know if you use the taglibs but you can use the url tag to generate a right URL:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:url var="myControllerVar" value="/myController" />
```

Then, put it in your AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "${myControllerVar}",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(msg) {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function(ob,errStr) {
        alert('onfailure');
    }
});
```

Else, you can try with the full path because I think the application context is missing. You can retrieve it with the following JSP var:

```
${pageContext.request.contextPath}
```

That will look like that:

```
${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myController
```

And you ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myController",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(msg) {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function(ob,errStr) {
        alert('onfailure');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use the following url in your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/myController",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(msg) {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function(ob,errStr) {
        alert('onfailure');
    }
});
```

I'm currently able to use this url to call my spring mvc controller. I'm doing an ajax call, as well, with an event listener on a submit button. The submit button then calls a function that contains the ajax call. I am using annotation based spring, and my controller is as so:

```
    @Controller
    public class myController{

        @ResponseBody
        @RequestMapping(value = "/myController", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView myControllerHandler(HttpServletRequest request)  {
              ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/success");
        return mv;
        }
    }
```

I am passing in a HttpServletRequest but am not using the request. I am returning a model and view that directs to a success.jsp page. I can include the code with my event listener and submit button if needed.